# Nodejs Mongoose - One databse call = two separate arrays sorted by different criteria

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Nodejs(express) + MongoDB and would like to ask if there's a way to access the database to get a set of documents(for simplicity let's say blog posts with likes count and views count properties), sort the result first by likes count a store it in array1 and then without calling the databse again sort it by views count and store it in array2, so the result will be:

- 1 databse access
- array1: blog posts sorted by likes count
- array2: blog posts sorted by views count

So basically I don't want to chain the sort queries but I want the output to be 2 arrays each sorted by different criteria. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Maybe my approach is totally wrong(I am not so experienced), but if each database access consumes server resources, then I think it's good to search the documents once and then make two arrays each sorted by different criteria vs. calling the database twice and then in first call sort the documents by views and second call sort by likes, or I am wrong?

Comment: get the sorted array array1 directly from query and then you can create array2 from array1 using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

where's the issue?

Comment: I was thinking the same but as mozilla says, the speed and space complexity of .sort() cannot be guaranteed and so what I was thinking is that the MongoDB sort algorithm would be quicker then javascript .sort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with aggregate with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) as follow:

```
db.blog.aggregate([
   {
      $facet: {
        sortByLikeCounts: [ { $sort: { likeCounts: -1 }} ],      // likeCounts is field name which is used to save total counts of like 
        sortByViewCounts: [ { $sort: { viewCounts: -1 }} ]       // viewCounts is field name which is used to save total counts of view
      }
   }
])
```

In result you will get two separate array sorted by different queries.

Comment: I tried it in Mongo shell and it does work. Thank you!